# Importing multiple files in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm very new to sparklyr and spark, so please let me know if this is not the "spark" way to do this.

#### My problem

I have 50+ .txt files at around 300 mb each, all in the same folder, call it `x`, that I need to import to sparklyr, preferably one table.

I can read them individually like

```
spark_read_csv(path=x, sc=sc, name="mydata", delimiter = "|", header=FALSE)
```

If I were to import them all outside of sparklyr, I would probably create a list with the file names, call it `filelist` and then import them all into a list with lapply

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".txt")
datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x)read.table(file = x, sep="|", header=FALSE))
```

This gives me a list where element *k* is the *k*:th .txt file in `filelist`. So my question is: is there an equivalent way in sparklyr to do this?

#### What I've tried

I've tried to use `lapply()`and `spark_read_csv`, like I did above outside sparklyr. Just changed `read.table` to `spark_read_csv` and the arguments

```
datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x)spark_read_csv(path = x, sc = sc, name = "name", delimiter="|", header=FALSE))
```

which gives me a list with the same number of elements as .txt files, but every element (.txt file) is identical to the last .txt file in the file list.

```
> identical(datalist[[1]],datalist[[2]])
[1] TRUE
```

I obviously want each element to be one of the datasets. My idea is that after this, I can just `rbind` them together.

### Edit:

Found a way. The problem was that the argument "name" in `spark_read_csv` needs to be updated for each time a new file is read, otherwise it will overwrite. So I did in a for loop instead of lapply, and in each iteration I change the name. Are there better ways?

```
datalist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(filelist)){
  name <- paste("dataset",i,sep = "_")
  datalist[[i]] <- spark_read_csv(path = filelist[i], sc = sc,
  name = name, delimiter="|", header=FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you (emphasis mine)

> have 50+ .txt files at around 300 mb each, **all in the same folder**

you can just use wildcard in the path:

```
spark_read_csv(
  path = "/path/to/folder/*.txt",
  sc = sc, name = "mydata", delimiter = "|", header=FALSE)
```

If directory contains only the data you can simplify this even further:

```
spark_read_csv(
  path = "/path/to/folder/",
  sc = sc, name = "mydata", delimiter = "|", header = FALSE)
```

Native Spark readers also support reading multiple paths at once (Scala code):

```
spark.read.csv("/some/path", "/other/path")
```

but as of 0.7.0-9014 it is not properly implemented in [sparklyr](/questions/tagged/sparklyr) ([current implementation of `spark_normalize_path`](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/blob/491194f64e92bc5985961e99f65a04fa9d5dffb6/R/utils.R#L235-L243) doesn't support vectors of size larger than one).